# Can I debug UWP winrt libraries? Does Microsoft provide symbol files for those libraries?

Tags: uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt, winrt-component

I am running into problems while developing a UWP app. So I was wondering if Windows provides symbol files for winrt components. Particularly I am looking to step into the function LoadComponentWithResourceLocation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.loadcomponent?view=winrt-22000) Can you point me how to load these symbols if that is even possible?
Thanks

Update:
Following is the dialog which pops up when trying to load Windows.UI.xaml.dll symbol files

[image]

Update 2:
Symbols for Windows.UI.xaml.dll are not loaded

[image]

Comment: [Specify symbol (.pdb) and source files in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger) for Visual Studio. [Symbol path for Windows debuggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbol-path) for WinDbg, KD, CDB, NTST.

Comment: I tried "Load all modules unless excluded" (there is nothing in excluded list) and it is not loading symbols for Windows.UI.Xaml.dll which I think has definition for LoadComponentWithResourceLocation.

Comment: Basically I need windows.ui.xaml.pdb. Does Microsoft provide this?

Comment: It is loading the symbols just fine. Make sure to give it enough time, though. Those XAML symbols are *massive*.

Comment: It is not loading this particular symbol. Because it has given up and pops up this dialog which is added above in the original question. It could not find that pdb file on the symbol servers configured. My symbol locations are - "Microsoft Symbol Server" and "Nuget.orgSymbol Server".

Comment: Following the steps in the guide above I get `Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll'. Symbols loaded.` in the debug output for a UWP application. Either you haven't set up the symbol server properly, or something else is happening (e.g. symbol download times out) on your end. Symbols for a trivial UWP application are in the gigabytes, so either cache them, or make sure your internet connection is up to the task.

Comment: Weird! It is not loading for me. Can you share your symbol file locations? There must be difference between your symbol file location on your system and mine.

Comment: There is no issue with internet connection speed. It is very good. My app is also not very big at the moment, only one xaml file. 300mb is the size of current Symbol cache folder. For me, all dlls do not load symbol files. So maybe I think I am missing a server location?

Comment: You are probably running into a silent download failure. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70052400/1889329) explains how to identify those failures. 300MiB of symbols seems way too little for a XAML application, even a tiny one.